# Finding list of offline partitions in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am getting alert that some partitions of my kafka clusters are offline. But I am not able to figure out which one. How can we find list of partitions that are offline.

Answer (score 0):

In older version of kafka, to see offline partitions  run the below command

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper_ip>:2181 --describe | grep "Leader: -1"
```

In the latest version of kafka instead of -1, None is being used.
To see offline partitions  run the below command

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper_ip>:2181 --describe | grep "Leader: None"
```

Comment: Zookeeper flag isn't accepted in latest version of Kafka, is it? You should use bootstrap servers

Comment: i could try that as well, by wanted to highlight Leader None, instead of -1 part. took me 1 hours to figure out and i was running like headless chicken

Comment: The output should be the same. Just wanted to clarify that Zookeeper is actively being removed from Kafka architecture